# Python: Read .txt file without putting its content in strings

Tags: python, readlines

I have created a .txt file which contains training data for a model. The training samples have a certain structure that looks like this:

```
("sample sentence",
{"entities": [ ]})
```

I have like 600 of those which I need to put in a list in python. However, when I do the 'normal' python reading with `file.readlines()` etc., I get all the samples imported as strings that are basically the following:

```
'("sample sentence",'
'{"entities": [ ]})'
```

what makes the training data invalid for the model.

So my question is how can I tell python to read the .txt file without any string formatting but rather just read it as it is?

//edit:

The .txt is a file with training data that fits the training process for the spaCy models following the NER annotation scheme. An example of the training data with the NER annotation scheme from the spaCy documentation page:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
     ("Uber blew through $1 million a week", {'entities': [(0, 4, 'ORG')]}),
     ("Google rebrands its business apps", {'entities': [(0, 6, "ORG")]})]
```

My .txt file looks exactly like this, except without the `[ ]` at the beginning and at the end of the .txt file and the line breaks in between. So this example would look like this in my .txt file:

```
("Uber blew through $1 million a week", 
{'entities': [(0, 4, 'ORG')]}),

("Google rebrands its business apps", 
{'entities': [(0, 6, "ORG")]})
```

Comment: Please add in your question example for an input file. Not just one object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with the following. It works correctly for your example. Try it out.

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
  TRAIN_DATA = literal_eval('[' + ''.join(f.readlines()) + ']')
```

or

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
  TRAIN_DATA = literal_eval('[' + f.read() + ']')
```

This reads the whole file and adds missing square brackets before evaluating.

Comment: Once you removed the line breaks, adding the wrapping parenthesis is unnecessary.

Comment: Depends on whether you need a list or tuple

Comment: True, but since the only difference is the list/tuple mutability and since the user is unlikely to add items, then it interchangeable.

Comment: I tried the first solution and it worked really fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to interpret the string into a Python object.
Without any more knowledge about the file structure, I will assume it arbitrarily break lines and without any separator between data object except a line break.

If this is the case, this code should work:

```
from ast import literal_eval
def iterate_objects(filename):
    cur_data = ""
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for l in f.readlines():
            cur_data += l
            try:
                yield literal_eval(cur_data)
            except:
                continue

TRAIN_DATA = list(iterate_objects(your_filename))
```

It tries to interpret the accumulated lines so far until it succeeds, then it yields the object and continues.

### Edit

Given the new .txt file example, a much simpler solution will work:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    TRAIN_DATA = list(literal_eval(f.read().replace('\n','')))
```

According to the given .txt example, the output `TRAIN_DATA` should be a tuple of all the data objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me an `unexpected EOF` error after the first comma that is after:

    ("sample sentence",

Comment: I also tried your Edit code example but it still gives me an error. This time an `invalid syntax` error right before the second sample. Not sure if the line break between the samples might be a problem for your solution

Comment: Have you used the latest edit? The one that removes the linebreaks?

Comment: No, I didn't see your edit. It works now without error but it puts all the content in round brackets. Do you know how to avoid this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: It doesn't matter. The round brackets are tuples and the square brackets are lists. As long as you are not adding items to the list yourself, there isn't much difference between them. It should work either way.

Comment: Well, I think the training process of the spaCy models includes shuffling the training data with the 'numpy.random.shuffle' function, thus I feel that the training data will be changed inplace and therefore it has to be a list. Sorry, not telling you beforehand as I just got to know this when I encountered the error. But in most cases, one should also be fine with your solution, I guess.